# Find deeper in dictionary or list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

guys, I have such question. Suppose that I have a dictionary/list that inside contains other dictionary/list and so on.

Example:

```
dict = {
'Domains':{
'Web':['JavaScript','PHP','Python'],
'Mobile':{'Android':'Java','iOS':['Swift','Objective-C'],'Windows Phone':'C#'},
'Desktop':['C#','Java','Python']}
}
```

And i want to find 'iOS' list in this dictionary. There is a way to call a function that will display value of an element if this element exist.
Example:

```
print(function('iOS'))

['Swift','Objective-C']
```

Comment: The easiest method would be to write a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a helper function to find all dicts:

```
def all_dicts(a_dict):
    yield a_dict
    for key in a_dict:
        if isinstance(a_dict[key], dict):
            yield from all_dicts(a_dict[key])
```

And now, the lookup function:

```
def lookup(a_dict, key):
    for d in all_dicts(a_dict):
        if key in d:
            return d[key]
```

To see it in action:

```
>>> d = {'Domains': {'Web': ['JavaScript', 'PHP', 'Python'], 'Desktop': ['C#', 'Java', 'Python'], 'Mobile': {'Android': 'Java', 'Windows Phone': 'C#', 'iOS': ['Swift', 'Objective-C']}}}
>>> lookup(d, 'iOS')
['Swift', 'Objective-C']
```

If dictionaries can also exist in lists, you can adjust `all_dicts` to also recursively step in those.